# How to merge dataset with different eventdates for different variables?

Tags: r, events, merge

I need your help working with my panel dataset. I have two datasets, the one is concerning the stock data (Symbol of the stock, Date, time and close) and the other dataset is containing the event dates (Eventdate, eventtime and the symbol of the stock). My problem is that I have different eventdates for different symbols, and I am not quite sure how to merge the both datasets within R.

I tried this:

> Companies_Events <- merge (Companies, Eventdates, by = c("Symbol", "date") , all = FALSE)

and I also tried just to add a column for just the events, but it also doesn't work and is returning me 0 values for the events..

> Companies$Events <- ifelse(Companies$date == Eventdates$date & Companies$time == Eventdates$time & Companies$Symbol == Eventdates$Symbol, 1, 0)

Both does not work, it is both returning me only 0 values for my dataset. Do you know maybe what I did wrong in the code?

My datasets looks like this but the goal is that the datasets are merged together.

```
   Symbol   Date    time        Close
A   12.03.2020  06:00   65,542503
A   12.03.2020  07:00   72,334999
A   12.03.2020  08:00   63,857498
A   12.03.2020  09:00   65,057499
A   12.03.2020  10:00   67,4925
A   12.03.2020  11:00   66,552502
A   12.03.2020  12:00   65,215
A   12.03.2020  13:00   66,6675
A   12.03.2020  14:00   62,195
A   12.03.2020  15:00   52,310001
A   12.03.2020  16:00   51,092499
A   14.03.2020  06:00   66,542503
A   14.03.2020  07:00   71,334999
A   14.03.2020  08:00   68,857498
A   14.03.2020  09:00   62,057499
A   14.03.2020  10:00   69,4925
A   14.03.2020  11:00   60,552502
A   14.03.2020  12:00   63,215
A   14.03.2020  13:00   61,6675
A   14.03.2020  14:00   61,195
A   14.03.2020  15:00   57,310001
A   14.03.2020  16:00   56,092499
B   12.03.2020  08:00   186,960007
B   12.03.2020  09:00   184,360001
B   12.03.2020  10:00   171,130005
B   12.03.2020  11:00   182,600006
B   12.03.2020  12:00   172,949997
B   12.03.2020  13:00   160,080002
B   12.03.2020  14:00   175,830002
B   12.03.2020  15:00   152,009995
B   12.03.2020  16:00   157,889999
B   12.03.2020  17:00   148,479996
B   12.03.2020  18:00   152,25
B   12.03.2020  19:00   146,830002
B   15.03.2020  08:00   134,960007
B   15.03.2020  09:00   135,360001
B   15.03.2020  10:00   140,130005
B   15.03.2020  11:00   145,600006
B   15.03.2020  12:00   147,949997
B   15.03.2020  13:00   138,080002
B   15.03.2020  14:00   137,830002
B   15.03.2020  15:00   136,009995
B   15.03.2020  16:00   138,889999
B   15.03.2020  17:00   132,479996
B   15.03.2020  18:00   130,25
B   15.03.2020  19:00   12,830002
```

And this:

```
Symbol      Event   Event1    Event1_date   Event1_time
A   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   12.03.2020  1     12/03/2020    10:00
A   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   14.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   14.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   14.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   14.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   14.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   14.03.2020  1     14/03/2020    11:00
A   14.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   14.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   14.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   14.03.2020  NA    NA    
A   14.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   12.03.2020  1     12/03/2020    13:00
B   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   12.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   15.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   15.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   15.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   15.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   15.03.2020  1     12/03/2020    12:00
B   15.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   15.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   15.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   15.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   15.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   15.03.2020  NA    NA    
B   15.03.2020  NA    NA
```

Can you please help me to merge the datasets correctly?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you `dput()` the two datasets!

Comment: Yes, of course. I have split them into two data sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case you could do a `cbind`:

```
cbind(df1, df2[,2:5])
```

or if you want to `join` or `merge`
you have to put an unqiue identifier in each df.

```
df1 <- df %>% 
    select(Symbol, Date, time, Close) %>% 
    mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number())

df2 <- df %>% 
    select(1, 5:8) %>% 
    mutate(across(c(Event, Event1_date), dmy)) %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number())
   
left_join(df1, df2)
```

Output:

```
`cbind(df1, df2[,2:5])
   Symbol       Date     time     Close      Event Event1 Event1_date Event1_time
1       A 2020-03-12 06:00:00  65542503 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
2       A 2020-03-12 07:00:00  72334999 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
3       A 2020-03-12 08:00:00  63857498 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
4       A 2020-03-12 09:00:00  65057499 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
5       A 2020-03-12 10:00:00    674925 2020-03-12      1  2020-03-12    10:00:00
6       A 2020-03-12 11:00:00  66552502 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
7       A 2020-03-12 12:00:00     65215 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
8       A 2020-03-12 13:00:00    666675 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
9       A 2020-03-12 14:00:00     62195 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
10      A 2020-03-12 15:00:00  52310001 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
11      A 2020-03-12 16:00:00  51092499 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
12      A 2020-03-14 06:00:00  66542503 2020-03-14     NA        <NA>          NA
13      A 2020-03-14 07:00:00  71334999 2020-03-14     NA        <NA>          NA
14      A 2020-03-14 08:00:00  68857498 2020-03-14     NA        <NA>          NA
15      A 2020-03-14 09:00:00  62057499 2020-03-14     NA        <NA>          NA
16      A 2020-03-14 10:00:00    694925 2020-03-14     NA        <NA>          NA
17      A 2020-03-14 11:00:00  60552502 2020-03-14      1  2020-03-14    11:00:00
18      A 2020-03-14 12:00:00     63215 2020-03-14     NA        <NA>          NA
19      A 2020-03-14 13:00:00    616675 2020-03-14     NA        <NA>          NA
20      A 2020-03-14 14:00:00     61195 2020-03-14     NA        <NA>          NA
21      A 2020-03-14 15:00:00  57310001 2020-03-14     NA        <NA>          NA
22      A 2020-03-14 16:00:00  56092499 2020-03-14     NA        <NA>          NA
23      B 2020-03-12 08:00:00 186960007 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
24      B 2020-03-12 09:00:00 184360001 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
25      B 2020-03-12 10:00:00 171130005 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
26      B 2020-03-12 11:00:00 182600006 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
27      B 2020-03-12 12:00:00 172949997 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
28      B 2020-03-12 13:00:00 160080002 2020-03-12      1  2020-03-12    13:00:00
29      B 2020-03-12 14:00:00 175830002 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
30      B 2020-03-12 15:00:00 152009995 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
31      B 2020-03-12 16:00:00 157889999 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
32      B 2020-03-12 17:00:00 148479996 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
33      B 2020-03-12 18:00:00     15225 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
34      B 2020-03-12 19:00:00 146830002 2020-03-12     NA        <NA>          NA
35      B 2020-03-15 08:00:00 134960007 2020-03-15     NA        <NA>          NA
36      B 2020-03-15 09:00:00 135360001 2020-03-15     NA        <NA>          NA
37      B 2020-03-15 10:00:00 140130005 2020-03-15     NA        <NA>          NA
38      B 2020-03-15 11:00:00 145600006 2020-03-15     NA        <NA>          NA
39      B 2020-03-15 12:00:00 147949997 2020-03-15      1  2020-03-12    12:00:00
40      B 2020-03-15 13:00:00 138080002 2020-03-15     NA        <NA>          NA
41      B 2020-03-15 14:00:00 137830002 2020-03-15     NA        <NA>          NA
42      B 2020-03-15 15:00:00 136009995 2020-03-15     NA        <NA>          NA
43      B 2020-03-15 16:00:00 138889999 2020-03-15     NA        <NA>          NA
44      B 2020-03-15 17:00:00 132479996 2020-03-15     NA        <NA>          NA
45      B 2020-03-15 18:00:00     13025 2020-03-15     NA        <NA>          NA
46      B 2020-03-15 19:00:00  12830002 2020-03-15     NA        <NA>          NA
```